# Using C++11 Range For To Replace All Characters In A String

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am new to C++, working my way through a book and am learning some great stuff. However, I am seriously stuck on one of the exercises and I can't figure the principle out.

The question calls for me to change all the characters in the string ("Hello World") to the letter X using the new **Range For** statement.

I was succesful in getting the correct output by entering this code:

```
 string initial ("Hello World!");
 for (auto &initChange : initial)
     cout << "X";
```

However I know this code is far from correct given that an example is to change all the text in the same string to uppercase uses the following:

```
string s("Hello World!!!");
for (auto &c : s)
    c = toupper(c);
cout << s << endl;
```

I understand this code, but I cannot get a variation of it to work for the purposes of the exercise.

I have been pulling my hair out for 2 days now to figure out this simple thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `algorithm` has algorithms for this.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: if the point of the exercise is to use the range-for statement though...

Comment: maybe I didn't understand the question, but if I did, can't you just replace `c = toupper(c)` with `c = 'X'`?

Comment: Note that your use of `toupper` is undefined behavior.  This function requires an `int`, not a `char` as parameter, and the values of `int` must correspond to those of an `unsigned char`, not a `char`.

Comment: @JamesKanze then how to use range for to iterate std::string?

Comment: @HongxuChen I'm not sure I understand your question.  But if you want to use any of the "functions" in `<ctype.h>` (or `<cctype>`), then you can't use them on a `char`.  If you want to use one as a predicate to `find_if`, or as the functional argument to `translate`, you'll have to wrap it in a functional object, explicitly converting the `char` argument to `unsigned char` before calling it.  (If you do any text processing at all, you'll have functional objects for these in your tool kit.  Using `std::ctype`, rather than the old C functions.)

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your words since I was thinking that you just meant that `toupper(c)` should not be used her for `for range`. Now I realized that the declaration of `toupper` is actually `int toupper ( int c );` in GNU/Linux environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple assignment should work:

```
std::string initial ("Hello World!");
for (auto& c: initial) {
    c = 'X';
}
std::cout << initial << '\n';
```

Note that `c = "X"` will not work because `"X"` is of type `char const[2]` (which degenerates to `char const*`) whilst `c` is of type `char`. `'X'` has the appropriate type: `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code gives the correct output, but doesn't do the right thing. It prints X's, but does not change the string.

The iteration variable (`initChange`) in your loop is a reference to the element of the string (a character); each iteraton, it refers to the next character in the string. You can use this reference to modify the character in the string (just as the `toupper()` example does):

```
string initial ("Hello World!");
for (auto &initChange : initial)
  initChange = 'X';
cout << initial;  //verify the original string is changed
```